# management endpoints throwing GroovyCastException when served on different port

Tags: spring-boot, grails, port, classcastexception, health-check

I have the following health management endpoints in my application.yml file

```
management:
  endpoints:
    health:
      sensitive: false
    web:
      base-path: /
```

and I have an interceptor with the following code

```
class TestInterceptor {

  TestInterceptor() {
    matchAll()
  }

  boolean before() {
    if (request.forwardURI?.endsWith('.json')) {
      // ... some code
      return false
    }
    true
  }
}
```

this is working great. The application is working on 8080.

**But** as soon as I change the port of management endpoints (so that health check is served on a different port), the following code

```
management:
  server:
    port: 8989
  endpoints:
    health:
      sensitive: false
    web:
      base-path: /
```

Ref# https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.1.7.RELEASE/reference/html/production-ready-monitoring.html

then the application is throwing a cast exception when accessing the request object in the interceptor

> org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request
> processing failed; nested exception is
> org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.typehandling.GroovyCastException: Cannot
> cast object 'Request(GET
> //localhost:8989/testApp/health)@68117e64' with class
> 'org.springframework.web.context.request.ServletRequestAttributes' to
> class 'org.grails.web.servlet.mvc.GrailsWebRequest'

any suggestion to fix the issue.

(Grails 4.0.12, Groovy 2.5.14 and Java 11)

Comment: The behavior you are seeing looks like a bug.  If you file an issue at https://github.com/grails/grails-core/issues we can investigate.  It is worth mentioning that the exception appears to be coming from https://github.com/grails/grails-core/blob/d8da09b025e04ce7601344c6d7161f518f8a6c76/grails-web-common/src/main/groovy/grails/web/api/WebAttributes.groovy#L47.

Comment: Issue Created https://github.com/grails/grails-core/issues/12140. Thank you @JeffScottBrown.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upgrade to Grails 5. The above functionality working fine with that.